# Can't find USB wireless adapter on 16.04

Tags: drivers, wireless, usb

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 as dual boot on my Dell Windows machine.  I don't have ethernet service, so I bought a Netgear USB adapter, which works in Windows, but not in Ubuntu.  lsusb does indeed show the adapter card as expected, Netgear WNA3100(v1).  But ifconfig returns lo and enp1s0 and nothing else, so maybe it needs drivers?  On this forum it was suggested that a solution would be to copy a couple *deb files to my home dir and run:

```
sudo dpkg -i *deb
```

which I did and it seemed to run successfully, but still no joy.

I cannot download drivers to this machine, since I cannot access the internet, but if I need to, I can download whatever files to USB and copy them over.

Here is output from lsusb:

```
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0846:9020 NetGear, Inc. WNA3100(v1) Wireless-N 300 [Broadcom BCM43231]
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1058:0820 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. My Passport Ultra (WDBMWV, WDBZFP)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID ffff:5678  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:0184 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5182 Card Reader
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 003: ID 413c:2107 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Here are the two files installed with dpkg

```
dkms_2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11.3_all.deb
bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu1~1.1_amd64.deb
```

And here is the outout of lsusb -t

```
/:  Bus 09.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 5000M
/:  Bus 08.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 480M
/:  Bus 07.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 5000M
/:  Bus 06.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
/:  Bus 05.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ohci-pci/2p, 12M
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ohci-pci/5p, 12M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ohci-pci/5p, 12M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/5p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 480M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/5p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
```

So looks like no driver.

Comment: Which deb's did you install? And please include the output of `lsusb -t`. [Edit] your question to add the information.

Comment: Please check here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2264020&highlight=Wna3100 I suggest you get a different device.

Comment: chili555 Thank you for the link.   I won't spend any more time on the device.